# count the subarrays with maximum element as k

Tags: python, optimization

Given an array and a number k, you need to count the number of subarrays in which k is the maximum.

For example, in the array [4,1,2,3,1,5] and k=3. So the count for this array would be 6.

I came up with the following solution:

```
count = 0
n = len(a)
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(i,n):
    b = a[i:j]
    if k in b and max(b) == k:
      count += 1

return count
```

The time complexity for this is O(n^2). How can I optimize it (using the two pointer approach, preferably) to get an O(n) solution?

Comment: Is `k` unique in the array or can the number appear more than once?

Comment: I'm currently looking for a solution where k is unique. But I'd appreciate a solution that would work when k occurs more than once as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for a unique `k` in the list:

```
k = 3
a = [4,1,2,3,1,5]
length = len(a)
ucount, lcount = 0, 0

# Find the index of k:
index = a.index(k)

# From this position, go in one direction until a larger number is found
# increment ucount for each step
upper = index
while upper < length and a[upper] <= k:
    ucount += 1
    upper += 1

# After that, go from index backwards until a larger number is found
# increment lcount for each step
lower = index
while lower >= 0 and a[lower] <= k:
    lcount += 1
    lower -= 1

# Multiply the upper and lower count
print(ucount*lcount)
```

Worst case, that's O(n) for finding the index and O(n) again for both while loops together. Which is still O(n) altogether.

Another solution would be collecting `lower`, `index` and `upper` while traversing the list once.

For multiple occurrences of `k` it gets more complicated, especially when they overlap (when they are connected by numbers < k).